# Azure Databricks integration with Unix File systems

Tags: azure, unix, azure-data-factory, databricks, azure-databricks

I am looking for help to understand the integration of Unix file system with Azure DataBricks. I would like to connect to on-Prem Unix file systems and access relevant files and process through DataBricks and load into ADLS Gen2.
I understand that if the files are available in DBFS, we should be able to process. But my requirement is specific to process files available on on-prem Unix file system using Azure Technologies such as Azure DataBricks or Azure DataFactory.
Any suggestion/help in this regard will be very helpful.

Comment: Unix file system is a broad term - what specific implementation is used?

Comment: If there is connectivity between your on-prem system and Databricks, try using SFTP.  Tools like lftp can help you to transfer big files from Linux to Databricks.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, it is not possible to directly connect to on-Prem Unix file systems.

However you can try below workarounds:

You can upload files onto DBFS, and then access them. [Browse DBFS using the UI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/data/databricks-file-system#browse-dbfs-using-the-ui)

To copy large files use [AzCopy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azcopy-v10). AzCopy is a command-line utility that you can use to copy blobs or files to or from a storage account.